# Set timestamp in output with Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm getting CSVs in a Kafka topic "raw-data", the goal is to transform them by sending each line in another topic "data" with the right timestamp (different for each line).

Currently, I have 2 streamers:

- one to split the lines in "raw-data", sending them to an "internal" topic (no timestamp)
- one with a `TimestampExtractor` that consumes "internal" and send them to "data".

I'd like to remove the use of this "internal" topic by setting directly the timestamp but I couldn't find a way (the timestamp extractor are only used at consumption time).

I've stumbled upon this line in the documentation:

> Note, that the describe default behavior can be changed in the Processor API by assigning timestamps to output records explicitly when calling #forward().

but I couldn't find any signature with a timestamp. What do they mean?

How would you do it?

Edit:
To be clear, I have a Kafka topic with one message containing the event time and some value, such as:

`2018-01-01,hello
2018-01-02,world`

(this is ONE message, not two)

I'd like to get two messages in another topic with the Kafka record timestamp set to their event time (2018-01-01 and 2018-01-02) without the need of an intermediate topic.

Comment: Does it need to be Kafka Streams, or would you be interested in an example with KSQL?

Comment: I'm using Kafka Streams only. If it's possible in KSQL, it means there is a way in Kafka Streams.

Comment: That's fine—I'll leave this for Kafka Streams experts to answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting the timestamp for the output requires Kafka Streams 2.0 and is only supported in Processor API. If you use the DSL, you can use `process()` or `transform()` to use those APIs.

As you pointed out, you would use `context.forward()`. The call would be:

```java
// new API
stream.process(new ProcessorSupplier() {
  public Processor get() {
    return new Processor() {
      // omit other methods for brevity
      // you need to get the `context` from `init()`

      public void process(Record r) {
        // some business logic

        // you can call #forward() as often as you want
        context.forward(r.withTimestamp(newTimestamp));
      }
    }
  }
});

// old API
stream.transform(new TransformerSupplier() {
  public Transformer get() {
    return new Transformer() {
      // omit other methods for brevity
      // you need to get the `context` from `init()`

      public KeyValue transform(K key, V value) {
        // some business logic

        // you can call #forward() as often as you want
        context.forward(newKey, newValue, To.all().withTimestamp(newTimestamp));

        return null; // only return data via context#forward()
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This approach does not work unfortunately:     @Override
    public <K, V> void forward(final K key, final V value, final To to) {
        toInternal.update(to);
        if (toInternal.hasTimestamp()) {
            recordContext.setTimestamp(toInternal.timestamp());
        } because of the NPE in recordContext = null;

Comment: The code snipped is incomplete. Note the comment `you need to get the context from init()' -- did you do this?

Comment: I did. Even once the context is initialized in `init()`, there's a problem with `recordContext` which is not possible to initialize in the client code.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:110)`

Comment: Maybe start a new question and share your code? Not sure atm what could be the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53169284/set-timestamp-in-output-with-kafka-streams-fails-for-transformations