# How to send headers using KStream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am working on a use case where I have created pipeline which sends data from mongo to elasticsearch.

Mongo -> Spring Boot -> Kafka -> Transformer(KStream) -> Kafka -> Consumer (Send to Elastic Search.)

I have to calculate time taken by record from Mongo to Elastic search. I thought of using Kafka Headers and keep forwarding their values in next Kafka Producer and at the end calculate same by subtracting from current timestamp.

I can send headers from producer but how to send same from Kafka Streams. In below code I want to send headers which I got while consuming inTopic and send them to outTopic.

```
private StreamsBuilder buildStream(final String bootstrapServers, final String inTopic, final String outTopic) {
    StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, String> kStream = streamsBuilder.stream(inTopic);

    kStream.filter(new Predicate<String, String>() {
        public boolean test(String s, String s2) {
            return true;
        }
    })
    .to(outTopic);
    return streamsBuilder;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but is there a particular reason you're using Spring boot as a consumer from Mongo rather than Debezium? Similarly, if you had ran Debezium, then you could use Elasticsearch Sink Connector as part of the same installation

Comment: it's already created but my question is more like how to send headers using stream.

Comment: Looking over `Keyvaluemapper` and `ValueMapper` Javadoc, I don't see headers as being exposed

Answer (score 2):

You can access headers in processor API by ProcessorContext and use DSL and processor API together.

What I would do is create my implementation of Transformer and use it in `transform()`. This question seems to be similar to yours and it has an answer with code snippet which I believe could be helpful: [Set timestamp in output with Kafka Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52438161/set-timestamp-in-output-with-kafka-streams)

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solutions seem to be based on `org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.Processor` that has been deprecated since version 3.0 in favor of `org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.Processor` and there is no access to headers via `context` anymore.

So the new way of doing this would be:

```
 streamsBuilder.<String, String>stream(inTopic)
    .processValues(() -> new FixedKeyProcessor<String, String, String>() {
          @Override
          public void process(FixedKeyRecord<String, String> record) {
              record.headers().add("header.key","header.value".getBytes());
          }
 }).to(outTopic);
```

Comment: To make this really work you would also need to forward the record in the context, otherwise it is not sent to the outTopic.

Answer (score 0):

@cody123  Please find the code using the ProcessContext and setting the headers . Let me know how it goes.

```
private StreamsBuilder buildStream(final String bootstrapServers, final String inTopic, final String outTopic) {
    StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, String> kStream = streamsBuilder.stream(inTopic);

    kStream.filter(new Predicate<String, String>() {
        public boolean test(String s, String s2) {
            return true;
        }
    }).process(() -> new Processor() {

        ProcessorContext context;

        @Override
        public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
          this.context = context;?
        }

        @Override
        public void process(Object key, Object value) {
            final Header header;
            try {
              header = new RecordHeader("key1",
                      new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes("value1"));
              this.context.headers().add(header);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
              if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.debug("Could not add content type header");
              }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void close() {

        }
      });
    .to(outTopic);
    return streamsBuilder;
}
```

/* implement the Header interface */

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.Header;

public class RecordHeader implements Header {
    private Object obj;
    private byte[] bytes;
    public RecordHeader(Object p0, byte[] bytes) {
        this.obj=p0;
        this.bytes=bytes;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return obj.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] value() {
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Never use a json deserializer to convert string to byte[]. It's a very smelly code. There's a basic method in the String class `getBytes()` https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(). Just read the javadocs

Comment: ^ +1, adding a header can actually be much simpler: `this.context.headers().add("key1", "value1".getBytes());`

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I used to solve same problem using org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.Processor;
and org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorContext

```
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.Processor;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorContext;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.Record;

public class HeaderAddingProcessor implements Processor<YourKey, YourValue, Void, Void> {
    private ProcessorContext context;

    @Override
    public void init(org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Record record) {
        record.headers().add("headerKey", "headerValue".getBytes());
        context.forward(record);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        
    }
}
```

and for your Kstream:

```
KStream<Key, Event> stream = kStreamBuilder
            .stream(inputTopic);
.....
                    .process(() -> new HeaderAddingProcessor())
            .to(outputTopic);
```